# Fix for Xcode's indiscernible highlighting of inline errors?

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode4, error-handling, syntax-highlighting

I can't be the *only one* that finds Xcode's method of "pointing out" where your mistakes are - ridiculous.  As helpful and essential as the feature is.. it does **not** help to make the line I need to fix *virtually impossible* to read or edit... let alone see...

[image: is it just me, or is this impossible to read?]
[image: you'd have thought they'd take into account people with dark backgrounds]
[image: errors are the hardest to see]

And don't get me started on the constant struggle to find a "selection" color that is visible, yet retains one's sanity/ability to **see what the selected text actually IS!**

[image: dont get me started]

What am I missing here?  I know how to futz with the colors in xCode, I know how to mess with the Appearance "Control Panel", but it all just results in different configurations  - of varying aesthetic quality - that are **all** hard to read...  I don't have this issue in TextMate...  Is that my answer?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the brilliant work, and answer by @amadillu, here is what the remarkably more usable Xcode looks like after installing his [Xcode 4 "Fix-Ins"](https://github.com/armadillu/Xcode-4-Fixins/tree/master/XCFixin_CustomizeWarningErrorHighlights)

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, the whole fix-ins backend isn't mine. They come davekeck. https://github.com/davekeck/Xcode-4-Fixins I just made one to solve our problem!

Comment: note: per discussion on the original question: this doesn't work for XCode 4.3 without tweaking it (reverting the last commit), only for XCode 4.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made an Xcode Plugin by using davekeck's "fixins" that allows you to customize the colors of the inline error and warning messages. This really helps if you use a dark scheme / background . See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574388/how-does-one-change-the-color-for-text-highlighting-in-xcode-4-for-warnings-and/10421842#10421842).

Comment: Wow.  Amazing. SO great.  These Fix-Ins solve almost ALL of my Xcode pet-peeves.  Is there one to fix [sytax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013437/why-does-xcode-4-3-syntax-highlighting-break-on-some-64-bit-projects), too? Or maybe re-enable plug-in support?  My compliments to the chef.