# Xcode 4: editing color of highlighted line

Tags: xcode, syntax-highlighting

In Xcode 4, how do I change the color of a line highlighted by error correction?

[image: example]

In this example, the first highlighted line correctly uses the color set by the "Selection" option in "Fonts&Colors", while the other one is highlighted clicking on its warning sign. How do I change that color?

Answer (score 3):

I've made an Xcode Plugin that allows you to customize the colors of the inline error and warning messages. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574388/how-does-one-change-the-color-for-text-highlighting-in-xcode-4-for-warnings-and/10421842#10421842).