# Change XCode execution line color in source code editor while debugging

Tags: xcode, xcode7, color-scheme

I have this (see picture below) in my XCode 7 source code editor window.  I can't read the line with the light green background - that's where the current execution pointer is while debugging.  I could not find an appropriate category in the fonts and colors section of preferences.  How can I change this color?

[image]

[EDIT]

I am not looking for a 3rd party software workaround, I want a native XCode solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one change the color for text highlighting in Xcode 4 for warnings and errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574388/how-does-one-change-the-color-for-text-highlighting-in-xcode-4-for-warnings-and)

Comment: @JAL Maybe, but 1) I was looking for a solution not requiring 3rd party software installation, which is basically a work-around, and 2) That solution is for Xcode 4 - which may still work in 7 but I don't have time or desire to try

Comment: If you are not part of the Xcode development team, Xcode is not designed for you, but you can use it if you want to. This has been the case since Xcode's inception. And thus the free nature of Xcode resulted in the lobotomization of the developer tool industry on Mac OS. Short story... When an Xcode project team member gets tired of green, you will be able to change the color... and not a moment before!