# Why does xCode 4.3 syntax highlighting break on some 64-bit projects?

Tags: xcode, macos, syntax-highlighting, automatic-ref-counting

I use XCode on many 64-bit projects, with no problem…  But many times, I will find that while a target is set for 64-bit, all-but-most-basic code-completion and syntax highlighting stops working.  This is the case whether ARC is enabled - *or not*.. (and yes, I know 32-bit isn't valid target under ARC, blah blah blah…  but the funny thing is.. Syntax highlighting usually DOES work on such a misbehaving project if then switched to 32 bit mode.  I have tried deleting "Derived Data", cleaning, analyzing, etc.   See below for an illustration of the issue.  This is on a 10.7.3, 12GB RAM, 8-Core 2008 MacPro.

You know what I'm talking about if up at the top, you see Xcode saying

`(Paused) Indexing…  0 of …`

Any ideas?

[image: 64bit woes.]

Comment: Xcode syntax highlighting is rapidly becoming a joke. I have to clear my derived data almost every day to kick it back into action.  How long have you let it sit after deleting the derived data?  Sometimes it takes a couple minutes for me.

Comment: I have discovered today that the QUICKEST way to get it to work is to go into `Product -> Edit Scheme -> ` and then Toggle Either / Or `Peristent State / Document Versions`.  This , so far, has instantly brought back syntax recognition, without further muss or fuss..  Does it work for you, @sudorm-rf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm, after several tests, that goint into `Product -> Edit Scheme ->` and then Toggle Either / Or `Peristent State / Document Versions` DOES fix this.

[image: toggle these]

Comment: Surprisingly enough, Xcode hasn't broken on me for a couple of days.  When it does break, and if this works, I'll be greatly obliged to you. ;)  And by the way, do you mind letting me know what theme you're using there?  Looks neat.

Comment: @sudorm-rf It's just the normal Dusk theme, but with colors I chose.. [Here is the Xcode theme](http://cl.ly/3m3f2s3f1e1M0M1r2X2u), you just put it in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/`.  You might simply be loving the font.  It is the ONLY font I can actually read.  Its the best.  It's called "Ubuntu Mono" (bold)…  It's new, so look around for it.. it's `monospaced`, and NOT the same as the "Other" Ubuntu fonts.  Glad it's working for ya.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the theme.  I'm loving it.  Unfortunately, syntax coloring broke for me on an iOS project, meaning that neither of these options are available to test.  Oh well.

Comment: @sudorm-rf make sure the source `.m` file in question is included under "Compile Sources" under "Build Phases".  Xcode will only check the syntax if the source is up for compilation for the ACTIVE target.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the problem.  I just restarted Xcode and it kicked it back into shape.  The file is compiling just fine.